# Revise an NxN for loop to be simpler

Tags: for-loop, kotlin

I want to make a multiplication table by using lambdas.
I made it, but I don't like the duplication of `(1..9).forEach{...}`.

How can I avoid this repetition?

```
(1..9).forEach { i ->
    (1..9).forEach {
        println("$i x $it = ${i * it}")
    }
}
```

Comment: `(1..9*9).forEach` ?

Comment: It's good. but I want print format is 'println("$i x $it = ${i * it}")'.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the nested loop?  There are other approaches, but all are likely to be more complex, or need third-party libraries; the nested loop is a common idiom and widely understood.

Comment: You could play with `${it % 9}` and `${it / 9}` to get rows and columns if you went to 1..81, but then again - why?

Comment: You're multiplying two vectors to produce a 2D array. A nested loop is the most sensible way to do it.

Comment: @soyLen You could put `(1..9)` in a variable, but that's it. You won't get around duplication of whatever you use for iteration.

Comment: maybe extract parts of the logic in its own function if that makes sense to you, e.g.: `fun multiplicateRange(range : IntRange, function : (Int, Int) -> Unit) { range.forEach { i -> range.forEach { j -> function(i, j) } }`  and call it similar to: `multiplicateRange(1..9) { i, j -> println("$i x $j = ${i * j}") }`... otherwise besides reusing te range I don't see much to improve...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes nested loops are best but there you go:

```
IntArray(81) { it / 9 + 1 }.zip(IntArray(81) { it.rem(9) + 1 }).forEach { 
    p ->
    println("${p.first} x ${p.second} = ${p.first * p.second}")
}
```